# Nesting Bootstrap container-fluid

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I'm building an html page containig various fieldset in main container. Every fieldset contains various input fields. I'm doing in this way:

```
<form>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

I think isn't correct to nest container-fluid but I tried this to get the right external and internal div padding.
I also tried to remove container-fluid class from external div and setting paddings. The result is also correct but I don't be sure the page is still responsive.
Is there a way to avoid nesting container-fluid class? Or my solution is accettable?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

1) You should always avoid nesting Bootstrap containers inside other containers.
While it is technically possible to nest them I can't think of a single case where it would be a good idea to do so. So, always avoid container nesting.

2) To make the Bootstrap grid work properly for you, you always need to put all of your normal content into one or more **columns**. 
The column/columns then go inside a **row**.
And a row goes inside a **container**.

So, **container > row > column** is the "holy trinity" you always want to maintain.
If you miss one of those 3 components you are going to run into problems because those 3 pieces are designed to work together.

In your code you are not using the columns is that's why you are missing the paddings. Add the column/columns inside the rows and Bootstrap will "auto-magically" give you the paddings you need and everything will be 100% responsive.

3) Always think twice (or 3 times) before using container-fluid. 
Because container-fluid will make the content span across the entire screen width and users with wide 4K monitors will hate you for that.

The following code is an example that would work pretty well:

```html
<form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col">
                    content goes here...
                </div>                
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col">
                    content goes here...
                </div>                
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: While it is not practical to use nested container, it is also common to use multiple container acting as a separate section,

Comment: It may be "common" in generic css, but in Bootstrap specifically, it's neither common nor recommended. This question is about Bootstrap specifically and not about generic css. The best practice in **Bootstrap** is to **avoid** nesting containers inside other containers.